# Cannot update from 10.15.2 to 10.15.6

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update

My wife's MacBook is currently running 10.15.2

She hasn't updated for some time, indeed she hasn't used the MacBook recently.

She tried to update, but had insufficient space.

We deleted some documents, and then tried to update.
This seemed to be OK, but on restart she was prompted to update to 10.15.4
This then was overwritten by an update to 10.15.6

We have tried several times but it remains on 10.15.2, and the whole cycle repeats.

How can we install updates?

Comment: Try the Combo Updater - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2048 How much free space does the drive have? Check in Disk Utility not 'manage storage', the Free value is more accurate for this purpose than the Available value.

Comment: Also consider making a backup of all your documents - 2 locations would be good and then making more space available for the install.

Comment: I managed to catch the prompt to update to 10.15.4 which I tried - and failed. After this the 10.15.6 update downloaded the update (which it hadn't been before) and it worked. I will certainly use the combo update if the situation ever arises again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to catch the prompt to update to 10.15.4 which I tried - and failed. After this the 10.15.6 update downloaded the update (which it hadn't been before) and it worked. I will certainly use the combo update if the situation ever arises again.